# How to make list of each separate word from a single line in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

1708:com.google.android.partnersetup/u0a120
this is line

I want output as :
['1708','com','google','android','partnersetup','u0a120']

I tried this

```
result_1 = [item.split(':')[0] for item in listli[8]]
print(result_1)
```

but it giving me the output :
['1', '7', '0', '8', '', 'c', 'o', 'm', '.', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'g', 'l', 'e', '.', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'o', 'i', 'd', '.', 'p', 'a', 'r', 't', 'n', 'e', 'r', 's', 'e', 't', 'u', 'p', '/', 'u', '0', 'a', '1', '2', '0']

can u plz help me to get me the output I want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

```
import re
pattern = r'[:.//]'
s = '1708:com.google.android.partnersetup/u0a120'
print(re.split(pattern, s))
```

Result:

```
['1708', 'com', 'google', 'android', 'partnersetup', 'u0a120']
```

Taken from this answer:
[Python 3: Split string under certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991123/python-3-split-string-under-certain-condition)

by [Jim Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4878850/jim-wright)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
result_1 = re.split('[:/ .]+', '1708:com.google.android.partnersetup/u0a120')
print(result_1)
['1708', 'com', 'google', 'android', 'partnersetup', 'u0a120']
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.